# How do I fix the "Duplicate sources.list entry" warning?

Tags: 12.04, apt

When I run `sudo apt-get install -f` I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libedbus1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

How do I fix these warnings?

Comment: If they are not in your main `/etc/apt/sources.list`, the duplicate entries could be in another list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`